# Conditional formatting based on time difference

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Basically I need to conditionally format a cell (o2) to highlight in red or what ever when its more than two mins different from another cell (d9).

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Conditional Formatting* -> *New Rule...* -> "Use formula to determine which cells to format":

[image: conditional formatting]

Now enter the following the following formula:

```
=ABS($A2-$D$9)>2/(24*60)
```

And change the *Format...*, then press OK, which results in:

[image: result]

In the formula `$A2` is the row of your data, `$D$9` the value you are comparing with, and 2/(24*60) are two minutes in days (since the dates have day as unit).

To change the rule: go to *Conditional Formatting* -> *Manage Rules...*